# Configure/Setup a Rails App to use both Mongodb and Mysql together

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nosql, mongomapper

Hi Is there a way to configure/setup a rail3 app to use two different data stores like MongoDB and Mysql at the same time.

Is there any common ORM for SQL/NoSql DB ?
If I have to use 2 different ORM like Active Record and MongoMapper how do I set this up or configure this in rails ?

If some one can explain this or point to some links that I can read would really be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both ActiveRecord and MongoMapper in a project, but if you want associations between records, you'll have to code the methods yourself (which is not that hard for the basic cases).

See http://mongomapper.com/documentation/getting-started/rails.html for setting up MongoMapper and Rails.

You might look also into DataMapper, which supports multiple backends.  I'm not sure if it can do multiple different types of DB's in one project though.  See http://datamapper.org/